# “Authors Response” or “Authors’ Response”?

Tags: editors, ieee

Recently, I received a decission letter from an IEEE journal. When I prepared my response, I became confused. The demand from editor is as follows:

> Please start your paper file with **an authors response to the review of [paper ID number]** which  contains how you responded to the reviewers comments.

My confusions are:

1. Which of the following titles should I use for my response?

   > An Authors Response to the Review of Paper XXX
   >   Authors Response to the Review of Paper XXX

   Should I drop *an* or not?
2. Which of the following should I use?

   > Authors Response to the Review of Paper XXX
   >   Authors**'** Response to the Review of Paper XXX

   Should I add an apostrophe at the end of *authors?*

Comment: The editor does not seem to be explicitly ask you to title a section anything, but given the editor's poor grammar, they will probably not be too stringent.  In any case, titling a section with proper grammar seems a reasonable thing to do.  (Your last option is gramatically correct, if you weren't sure about that.)

Comment: @Kimball Is it not only correct if there is more than one author? (or it should have been author's).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, though _authors'_ is also okay as a generic statement (e.g., the editor could use _authors'_ as part of a generic email in cases of both single-author and mutiple-author papers).  The OP did not list the singular possesive _author's_ as an option, so I didn't get into that, but from a submission point of view, this is all less than crucial anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I really doesn't matter: all of these are close enough to one another to be clearly sensible and have plausible arguments for why they might be reasonable. More importantly, none of them will make it into the published paper: they are merely a transient piece of communication between you and the editor and reviewers which will later be deleted.  As such, any of them is reasonable enough.

That said, personally, I would just say "Response to Reviews" and avoid the whole question.